# How to load image to android and resize

Tags: android, image, opencv, resize

I am trying to load an image in a mat and resize it with the below code

```
        Mat temp1= new Mat();
        int[] train_responses = null;
        Mat temp2 = new Mat();
        Mat temp3 = new Mat();
        Mat train_samples = new Mat();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++){            
            temp1 = Highgui.imread("/mnt/sdcard/images/train/" + ii + ".png");
            Imgproc.resize(temp1, temp2, new Size(30,20));  
        }
```

but the code crashes with the following log

```
opencv error assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in void cv::resize....
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that all your png images 0.png, 1.png, ... 9.png all exist, are in the correct location and have non-zero dimensions when you load them via imread. There's nothing otherwise wrong with the code - it works for me when I load my own png image using your code.